# How do I access a directory path in asp.net core from server side code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hosting, environment

I'm trying to get the current directory path from server side code.  In asp.net we used `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` to get the path.  But it's different with asp.net core we're supposed to use `IHostingEnvironment` to get the path.  As far as I know it's only used in the StartUp class and in Controllers but what I'm trying to do is use it in a server side class. How do I do that?

I've tried to pass the `IHostingEnvironment` value to the constructor of a server side class but it sets it to null.  Nothing else was added in the StartUp class.

I also tried to look for any help on the internet and couldn't believe there was nothing that can help me to set the value in a server side class.

Here's an example of my code:

```
public class PathHelper
    {
        private static IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;


        public PathHelper(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = environment;
        }

        public static string RootPath
        {
            get
            {
                return _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            }
        }
```

The error I get is

> null reference at the constructor level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best option, but this is what I currently doing right now.

I pass the `IHostingEnvironment` to static class to be used globally and init on `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`.

```
public static class Context
{
    public static IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment;
}
```

Assign on `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //.....
        namespace.Context.HostingEnvironment = env;
    }
```